# How should i store post views in sql on same table or on differet

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an articles site. Should I store articles views on the same table

e-g: should i create a views field in site_ARTICLES table or i should create a new table for that (site_articles_views)..

which one is most optimized?

which one way will create low load on sql database?

Comment: On the same table as what, resp. what do you mean with articles views?

Comment: e-g: mean i want to store article views.i just want to know that should i create a field in the same table [site_articles] or i should create a new table for article views

Comment: Yes, and what do you mean with sites views?

Comment: Probably means just how often an article has been opened. For that certainly an additional column inside the existing article table makes sense, since it saves you from having to make another join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store article views in your `site_articles` table if you need nothing more than a simple `count(*)` of them. You could then just increment a new `article_views` column when a particular article is viewed:

```
UPDATE site_ARTICLES SET article_views = article_views + 1 
WHERE ...
```

If however, you want to do more, such as:

- Display a list of unique viewers
- Count individual viewers
- Present or analyse statistics on the views
- Provide a viewing history for a user
- etc...

Then you should use a separate table - perhaps with the following as potential columns:

```
id
user_id
date_stamp
article_id
```

It depends entirely on what you want to achieve. Just a new `article_views` column would be "most optimized", but only if that is the limit of the functionality required.

Comment: And if the number of views might exceed 1m, then a good solution is to not use count(*) but rather estimating the number of views based on the table information, which might be less accurate but it sure is fast.